# Exponential of a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential, sparse-matrices

### Problem definition

Given an integer $N>1$, let $A_N$ be the following $N\times N$ matrix
\begin{equation*}A_N\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_{N-1} \\
\hline
0_1 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
where $0_{a}$ is a $a\times a$ matrix with each entries equal to zero and $I_a$ is the $a\times a$ identity matrix. The north west block and the south east block are completed with zeros.

I'm interested in the explicit expression its exponential $F_N$ for any given $N$
\begin{equation*}F_N\triangleq \exp(A_N)\end{equation*}

### Partial solution

Since $A_N$ is sparse, I think that the most straightforward way to get the answer consists in using the definition of matrix exponential
\begin{equation*}\exp(A_N)\triangleq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{A_N^k}{k!}\end{equation*}
using this formula, the problem reduces to compute the powers of $A_N$.

I've noticed, by considering the special cases with $N\triangleq 2$ and $N\triangleq 3$, that as the exponent $k$ increase the identity block inside $A_N$ reduce its dimension until it vanishes.
My conjecture, by denoting as $0_0$ and $I_0$ an empty block of numbers, is that
\begin{equation*}A_N^k\triangleq \left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_{N-k} \\
\hline
0_k & 
\end{array}\right] \qquad k=0,1,\dots,N\end{equation*}
and $A_N^k=0_N$ for all $k>N$.

#### example 1: $N\triangleq2$

\begin{equation*}
A_2^0\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_{2} \\
\hline
0_0 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_2^1\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_1 \\
\hline
0_1 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_2^2=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_0 \\
\hline
0_2 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}

#### example 2: $N\triangleq3$

\begin{equation*}
A_3^0\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_3 \\
\hline
0_0 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_3^1\triangleq\left[\begin{array}{ccc} 
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_2 \\
\hline
0_1 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_3^2=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_1 \\
\hline
0_2 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
A_3^3=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
 & I_0 \\
\hline
0_3 & 
\end{array}\right]\end{equation*}

## Question

Is it true my conjecture? In that case, how can it be proven?

Comment: Yes, it's true, and that's because $A_N$ is nilpotent. Therefore the exponential series is finite and you can compute directly $\exp(A_N)$. To prove $A_N^N=0$, you may consider what the columns of $A_N$ actually represent (the images of basis vectors by a linear map, and here you are simply "shifting" vectors).

Comment: Your $A_N$ matrix is a [Jordan block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#Using_the_Jordan%E2%80%93Chevalley_decomposition) matrix for an eigenvalue of zero.